# Invalid Markup XAML Designer When Inheriting From Base Class in Separate Assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, designer

I'm trying to create a series of WpfUserControls in Visual Studio.  I have a base class called `BindableBase` that takes care of all the boiler plate `INotifyPropertyChanged` stuff that resides in a "Core" library.  All my ViewModels inherit from `BindableBase` so when I attempt to set the data context in XAML:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

I get the Designer "Invalid Markup" error.  When I inspect my code I'm being told that *The name "MyViewModel" does not exist in the namespace [UI Namespace].*  I know this isn't true because I can build and run the project just fine with no problems, it's just the design time features that I am missing.

I've tracked the issue down to my `BindableBase` class that is in a separate assembly.  If I move it to the assembly with my ViewModel and View everything works great, but when I move it back to the "Core" namespace design-time features break.

Is there a way to get around this issue?  Moving my `BindableBase` class is not an option because we have multiple UI assemblies that all have to reference that class.

Comment: Does the `BindableBase` share the same namespace as `MyViewModel`, if not you may have to add a `xmlns` reference to that namespace(or `using` in the code behind)

Comment: No they are in different namespaces.  I've already tried including the additional namespaces in XAML and code-behind but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too sometimes. I generally try Cleaning and Rebuilding my solution after restarting and reopening it. If this fails, I delete the problematic code, save and then restart Visual Studio and reopen the solution and retype the code, followed by a Clean and Rebuild if necessary.